# How to determine size of a huge binary file in c++

Tags: c++, binary

To determine a size of a binary file seems to always involve read the whole file into memory. How do I determine the size of a very large binary file which is known way bigger than the memory can take?

Comment: The file system knows how big it is - ask it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On most systems, there's [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) and 
[`fstat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html) functions (not part of ANSI-C, but part of POSIX). For Linux, look at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat).

EDIT: For Windows, the documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246905%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

EDIT: For a more portable version, use the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
  {
    std::cout << "Usage: tut1 path\n";
    return 1;
  }
  std::cout << argv[1] << " " << file_size(argv[1]) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The functions [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) and
[`fstat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html) are part of POSIX.  One works with a file name, the other with an open file descriptor.  You're correct that they're not part of Standard C.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <cstdio>

FILE *fp = std::fopen("filename", "rb");
std::fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
long filesize = std::ftell(fp);
std::fclose(fp);
```

Or, use `ifstream`:

```
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream fstrm("filename", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
fstrm.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
long filesize = fstrm.tellg();
```

Comment: This works nicely unless you're on a system with 32-bit `long` integers (32-bit Unix, or Windows — 32-bit or 64-bit) and the file is 2 GiB or larger.  Then you have a problem — you can't fit the extra bits needed to represent the size accurately into a 32-bit value.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
uintmax_t file_size(std::string path) {
  return std::ifstream(path, std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate).tellg();
}
```

Comment: Your answer works only for files smaller than 4G (not "huge" binary files as mentioned in the question).

Comment: @StamenRakov care to elaborate? "tellg" returns a 64 bit unsigned to be

Comment: but returning 'uintmax_t' is not 64bit.

Comment: In my platform, it's 128 bits... Hence the question.

Comment: Yes, it'll work for you, but not for me and all other people using 32-bit platforms.